# DateDiff Access Query returning #Error

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to get the number of days between two dates.
Here is the Expression I am using in Access Query Designer. (Access 2007)

```
Expr1: DateDiff('d',[Accept Date],[Sent Date])
```

The query is returning #Error.

The [Accept Date] and [Sent Date] format is yyyymmdd and the Data Type is TEXT.
I changed it to Date/Time but Access purged the data.

Here is the SQL behind the Query if that helps:

```
SELECT RTG.[PRO NO], RTG.[Service], RTG.[Sent Date], RTG.[Accept Date], DateDiff('d',[Accept Date],[Sent Date]) AS Expr1
FROM RTG
WHERE (((RTG.[PRO NO Prefix])<>"215") AND ((RTG.[Invoice Number])="8548"));
```

This has got to be something simple, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DatePart` can accept dates which are actually text instead of Date/Time datatype.  However, the text must be something which Access recognizes as a valid date representation.  A text date in *"yyyymmdd"* format doesn't satisfy that requirement.  For example, in the Immediate window ...

```vb
? IsDate("20141009")
False
```

However, if you insert dashes between the year, month, and day segments, Access can recognize the text string as a date.

```vb
? Format("20141009", "0000-00-00")
2014-10-09
? IsDate(Format("20141009", "0000-00-00"))
True
```

Test that technique in a simple query to make sure it avoids the error.

```sql
SELECT
    RTG.[Sent Date],
    RTG.[Accept Date],
    DateDiff(
        'd',
        Format([Accept Date],'0000-00-00'),
        Format([Sent Date],'0000-00-00')
    ) AS Expr1
FROM RTG
```

If Access still throws an error, use `CDate` to cast the text date to Date/Time datatype.

```sql
    DateDiff(
        'd',
        CDate(Format([Accept Date],'0000-00-00')),
        CDate(Format([Sent Date],'0000-00-00'))
    ) AS Expr1
```

Your task would be less challenging with actual Date/Time fields.  You could create new Date/Time fields and execute an `UPDATE` query to load the transformed values from the old text date fields.

Comment: ...I didn't need to use CDate().